# Почему изменяя значения одного массива в Java сразу меняется и второй?

Tags: java

*Допустим у нас есть массив из трёх целых чисел `array2`, и как-нибудь его инициализируем.*

```
int[] array2 = new int[3];
array2[0] = 0;
array2[1] = 3;
array2[2] = 5;
```

*Создаём его клон и забираем все значения у `array2`.*

```
int[] array3 = new int[3];
array3 = array2;
```

*Его значения начинаем изменять...*

```
array3[0] = 1;
array3[1] = 2;
array3[2] = 3;
```

*И, отлаживая, с ужасом обнаруживаем, что значения `array3 = {1,2,3}` и `array2` почему-то тоже стал `{1,2,3}` вместо должных `{0,3,5}`*

Как сделать так, чтобы области памяти, на которые ссылаются оба массива стали отличными друг от друга и как вообще в таком случае задавать переменные?

Comment: Вы присвоили ссылку на array2 массиву array3, а по этой ссылке лежат значения array2

Comment: Допустим это ссылка, но как же сделать чтобы объекты стали самостоятельными?

Comment: ответили уже, ниже

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В строке:

```
array3 = array2;
```

ссылка `array2` копируется в объект `array3`. Следовательно, после выполнения этой строки, `array2` и `array3` будут ссылаться на одну и ту же область памяти.

Скопировать сами значения можно, например, так:

```
System.arraycopy(array2, 0, array3, 0, array2.length);
```

Так же можно использовать `Arrays.copyOf(...)`, `Object.clone()` или копирование элементов одного массива в другой в цикле (здесь это возможно, так как заданный массив хранит элементы *примитивного типа*).